# Update binary to latest version using composer

Tags: php, phantomjs, composer-php

I'm using a Laravel package ([BrowserShot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot)) that has a dependency on phantomjs. It includes this by stating in composer.js:

```
"bin": [
    "bin/phantomjs"
],
```

Doing a `composer update` installs the phantomjs binary into vendors/bin/phantomjs, but it seems to be an out of date version (1.9.7) instead of (2.0.0).

I can't find any documentation on how to set which version a binary dependency should be using composer.

Is there anyway to do this without having to manually build a new binary and copy it into `vendors/bin/phantomjs` ?